# server side processing , filter datatables using laravel 8

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, server-side

I'm trying to hide rows from datatable based on a value of a column , hde rows with column `actif = 0` using server side processing.

So I'm using th following code

My script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  

$('#hide').click(function(){
alert("in");

if (!$.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#datatableRows')) {
 
 //  $('#datatableRows').DataTable().destroy();
  var table = $('#datatableRows').DataTable({

        
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
         var actif = $(this).attr('actif');
        ajax:{

         url: "{{ route('castingss.filter_status') }}",
          data:actif
        },
        columns:[
        
         {
          data: 'photo',
          name: 'photo',
          render: function(data, type, full, meta){

                    return "<img src={{ URL::to('/') }}/castingimages/" + data +  " class='list-thumbnail responsive border-0 card-img-left' />";
          },
          orderable: false
         },
         {data:'nom',
          name: 'nom',
          render:function(data,type,full,meta){
            return "<a href='profile'>" + data + "</a>";
          }
         },
          {
          data: 'cine',
          name: 'cine'
         },
         {
         data:   "tel1",
         name:   "tel1"
         },
        
         
         {
          data: 'action',
          name: 'action',
          orderable: false
         }
        ] 
       });
  
}
 });

</script>
```

My controller :

```
function filter_status(Request $request)
{
    if(request()->ajax())
    {
        if($request->actif = 0)
      {
       $data = DB::table('castings')
         ->where('actif', array($request->actif = 1))
         ->get();
         dd($data);
      }
       return datatables()->of($data)->make(true);
    }
    return view('Casting.castingss');
}
```

My route :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth','role:admin']], function() { 
   Route::get('castingss/filter_status', [App\Http\Controllers\CastingController::class, 'filter_status'])->name('castingss.filter_status');
});
```

for the time being I have the folowing error in console :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

**Updated**

there is my network tab->XHR when I clicked on the button Hide

[image]

is there something wrong with my code, what is preventing lines from hiding?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Hi, shift `var actif = $(this).attr('actif');` line  directly here `data:$(this).attr('actif');` .

Comment: @Swati , thank you it resolves my problem , but still any thing occur when I click on button hide , I put an alert inside the event , the alert displays , but the process of my function in controller doesn't work , 
can my route be the problem, because no error is displayed, it is as if it does not call the function which is controller ?

Comment: Check network tab->XHR is ajax call intiated or not .

Comment: @Swati , check my update

Comment: Is your code go inside if-statement or not ? Also , any error in console ?

Comment: I removed the if statement , and still nothing occurs